# How to make TwoWay binding on properties of ObservableCollection of custom class using mvvm pattern?

Tags: wpf, binding, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have the following class:

```
public class UserGroup
{
   public string GroupName { get; set; }
   public bool IsIntheGroup{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to bind an ObservableCollection of UserGroup items to listbox containing checkbox’s for each item in the collection and the checkbox is cheked based on the IsIntheGroup  property of the UserGroup. In my ViewModel I made an ObservableCollection of the UserGroup class:

```
public ObservableCollection<UserGroup> Groups { get; set; }
```

and loaded its contents (instances of UserGroup) from my database model

I used the following code in my view:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Groups, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsIntheGroup, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The problem is I am not notified when the user checks/unchecks a check box in the list so my two way binding failed…

How do I do a two way binding in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

Your UserGroup class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and each property of that class should invoke the PropertyChanged event in their setters.  ObservableCollection will only notify the UI of additions of removals from the collection, and not property changes of each individual instance in the collection.

Comment: And any idea on how to reflect that to my collection in the ViewModel? I mean how to refresh the ObservableCollection with the modificatins so that I can use it to update my database

Comment: If you implement INPC, you should find that the binding works both ways, I.e any programatical changes to items in the collection will be updated in the UI, and any UI changes invoked by the user will update the collection instances.  You can then traverse the ObservableCollection on any Save or Apply verb on the view model in order to persist the changes.